# Web Scraping using Rvest and Stringr: Can't figure out what I'm doing wrong

Tags: r, rvest, stringr

I have a code to scrape a senate website and extract all the information about representatives in a data frame. It runs fine up until I try to scrape the part about their term information. The function I'm using just returns "NA" instead of the term assignments. Would really appreciate some help in figuring out what I'm doing wrong in the last block of code (baselink3 onwards).

```
install.packages("tidyverse")
install.packages("rvest")
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

library(stringr)

#Create blank lists

member_list <- list()
photo_list <- list()
memberlink_list <- list()
cycle_list <- list()


#Scrape data

cycles <- c("2007","2009","2011","2013","2015","2017","2019","2021")
base_link <- "https://www.legis.state.pa.us/cfdocs/legis/home/member_information/mbrList.cfm?Body=S&SessYear="
for(cycle in cycles) {
  member_list[[cycle]] <- read_html(paste(base_link, cycle, sep="")) %>% 
    html_nodes(".MemberInfoList-MemberBio a") %>% 
    html_text()
  memberlink_list[[cycle]] <- read_html(paste(base_link, cycle, sep="")) %>% 
    html_nodes(".MemberInfoList-MemberBio a") %>%
    html_attr("href")
  photo_list[[cycle]] <- read_html(paste(base_link, cycle, sep="")) %>% 
    html_nodes(".MemberInfoList-PhotoThumb img") %>%
    html_attr("src")
  cycle_list[[cycle]] <- rep(cycle, times = length(member_list[[cycle]]))
}


#Assemble data frame

member_list2 <- unlist(member_list)
cycle_list2 <- unlist(cycle_list)
photo_list2 <- unlist(photo_list)
memberlink_list2 <- unlist(memberlink_list)
senate_directory <- data.frame(cycle_list2, member_list2, photo_list2, memberlink_list2) %>% 
  rename(Cycle = cycle_list2, 
         Member = member_list2,
         Photo = photo_list2,
         Link = memberlink_list2)


#New Section from March 12
##Trying to use each senator's individual page

#Convert memberlink_list into dataframe 
df <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(memberlink_list), nrow=394, byrow=TRUE),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)


colnames(df) <- "Link" #rename column to link




base_link3 <- paste0("https://www.legis.state.pa.us/cfdocs/legis/home/member_information/", df$Link) #creating each senator's link

terminfo <- sapply(base_link2, function(x) {
  val <- x %>%
    read_html %>%
    html_nodes('div.MemberBio-TermInfo') %>%
    html_text() %>%
    str_extract('(?<=Senate Term )\\d+')
  if(length(val)) val else NA
}, USE.NAMES = FALSE)  


terminfo <- data.frame(terminfo, df$Link)
```

Comment: I am looking at an [example](https://www.legis.state.pa.us/cfdocs/legis/BiosHistory/MemBio.cfm?ID=2650&body=S) of base_link3 and I can´t find any Senate Term... could you specify which information you are looking for with an example url of base_link3 to a page that works? That way we also don´t have to download all the previous data.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly you are looking for, but something like this might help you. Note that the page has a crawl delay of 5 seconds. Something you did not implement or respect in your code above. See [here](https://www.legis.state.pa.us/robots.txt)

```
library(httr)
library(purrr)
  
extract_terminfo <- function(link) {
  html <- httr::GET(link)
  Sys.sleep(runif(1,5,6))
  val <- html %>%
    content(as = "parsed") %>% 
    html_nodes('div.MemberBio-TermInfo') %>%
    html_text() %>%
    str_extract('(?<=Term Expires: )\\d+')
  if(length(val)>0){
    return(data.frame(terminfo = val, link = link))
  } else {
    return(data.frame(terminfo = "historic", link = link))
  }
}
link <- base_link3[1]
link

extract_terminfo(link)

term_info <- map_dfr(base_link3[1:3],extract_terminfo)
```